# What are the web_merged.xml and ibm-metadata.xml files generated by websphere deployment?

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, websphere-8

We have an automated process to deploy ear application on websphere 8.5.
During this process the files web_merged.xml and ibm-metadata.xml are generated in a way which does not let the application working well.
If we deploy the application using usual manual update in WAS Console the two files are newly generated in correct way and the application works well.

- What are those two files?
- Would be correct to include them in package before the EAR is deployed?
- Or they have to be generated by deployment process, they would be overwritten?

  - In this case maybe the team supevisioning the automated process of deploy should review the process to create them correctly?

EDIT:

I generally agree with F Rowe answer, at this time it's not possible for us to install patch on server. For now I'm temporarily solving installing the ear in another websphere test server in which I have direct access, then export the ear file from eclipse. This ear has the files generated and the web.xml modified to not regenerate them newly when deploying. I'm using it for final deploy... that's all in the meanwhile that I wait for updating the server and check for real solution...

Answer (score 2):

What are those two files? ibm-metadata.xml contains the result of the annotation scan, web_merged.xml is the result of merging the web.xml deployment descriptor and that metadata.

Would be correct to include them in package before the EAR is deployed? According to this [IBM support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PI77392),

> the IBM recommendation is to remove any pre-generated metadata from an
> application before deploying the application.

Or they have to be generated by deployment process, they would be overwritten?  They will be generated by the deployment process and overwritten.

Do you have one of the fix pack levels containing the APAR described in the above referenced page?  If not, you should install one of them and see if it fixes your problem since your description seems to match the problem solved in that APAR.